# Angularjstable example

Tags: angularjs

hai guys i got data from restfull web service to angular function i need to place this data in the form table but i am not getting the code so pls help me my code is. I need to show in table form what i get in json pls suggest me

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function ContactController($scope,$http) {
     //   $scope.contacts = ["hi@email.com", "hello@email.com"];

        $scope.add = function() {


      $http.get('http://localhost:8080/ProjectManagement/REST/GetProject/Details').success(function(data, status, headers, config,response){

            var json = JSON.stringify(data);

            var getresponseText = JSON.parse(json);
            var prjdetails=getresponseText.responseText;

            var fields = getresponseText.split("|");
            $scope.people = [];

            var projectid = fields[0];
            var projectname = fields[1];
            var claintid = fields[2];
            var projectstatus = fields[3];
            var prjstartdate = fields[4];
            var prjenddate = fields[5];
            var lastmodified = fields[6];
            var prjpinurl = fields[7];

            claim = '';

            claim = '{ "records":[{';
            claim += '"projectid": "'+ projectid+ '", ';
            claim += '"projectname": "'+ projectname+ '", ';
            claim += '"claintid": "'+ claintid+ '", ';
            claim += '"projectstatus": "'+ projectstatus + '", ';
            claim += '"prjstartdate": "'+prjstartdate+ '", ';
            claim += '"prjenddate": "'+ prjenddate + '", ';
            claim += '"lastmodified": "'+ lastmodified + '", ';
            claim += '"prjpinurl": "'+ prjpinurl + '", ';
            claim += '}]}'; 



        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config,response) {


        });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it is some what urgent if u know pls send me the code pls

Comment: What error message do you receive, if any?

Comment: i am not getting any error but i dot know to place json format in to table

Answer (score 0):

If you get json returned from the server, do not call `JSON.stringify` since it is already "stringified" when sent from the server.

It is not possible to help you further without seeing the actual response from the server.